# Regex String.split( )

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm using java to split a String of the form:

```
String stringToSplit = "AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK";
```

I'm using

```
String[] tokens = stringToParse.split("\\s");
```

to split the strings along whitespace, giving:

```
tokens = {"AAA","BBB","CCC", "DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH","III", "JJJ", "KKK"}
```

What I need to do now is split along whitespace for most of them, but also keep some strings together in specific cases.  For instance, I want "CCC DDD" and "III JJJ KKK" to stay as their full strings when I split.  So I want my array of tokens to be:

```
tokens = {"AAA","BBB","CCC DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH","III JJJ KKK"}
```

What regex would I use?  Is this possible?

Comment: If the format is fixed, you can use `substring()` instead of regex.

Comment: First of all, on what basis did you decide them to be together? And how are you getting that string? Can't you somehow have a different delimiter between them. Think of these questions, and may be your problem would become easier.

Comment: Its not my format.  I'm parsing some weather data, almost all of it is simple tokens delimited by whitespace, except for two cases where I have one token of data with a space in the middle like CCC DDD.

Answer (score 6):

You could replace ccc ddd with ccc_ddd and then covert the underscore back to a space later.

You might want to invest in some kind of syntax parser if you're going to be doing lots of this kind of thing

Comment: Didn't think of this... it could work.  I'm new to regex, so I thought maybe there was a way to do it natively.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `split()`, you could use the following method where you find all consecutive non-whitespace characters, but use alternation to also match your specific target strings that contain whitespace:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CCC DDD|III JJJ KKK|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ KKK");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/AxI1CV